# Javascript to provide the new coordinate of svg after transform

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working with a svg element

[image: S1]

and the markup is following

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

var fill1 = "#e6e6e6";

var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var widthMid = width / 2;
var heightMid = height / 2;
var zeroX = 0;
var zeroY = 0;

let bg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
bg.setAttribute("class", "bg");
bg.setAttribute("id", "bg");
bg.setAttribute("width", width);
bg.setAttribute("height", height);
bg.setAttribute("fill", fill1);

svg.appendChild(bg);

let ln1 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'line');
ln1.setAttribute("x1", widthMid);
ln1.setAttribute("y1", zeroX);
ln1.setAttribute("x2", widthMid);
ln1.setAttribute("y2", height);
ln1.setAttribute("stroke-width", ".5");
ln1.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
ln1.setAttribute("class", "XAxis");
ln1.setAttribute("title", "xAxis");

svg.appendChild(ln1);

let tl1 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'title');
tl1.textContent = "XAxis";
svg.appendChild(tl1);

ln1.append(tl1);


let ln2 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'line');
ln2.setAttribute("x1", zeroX);
ln2.setAttribute("y1", heightMid);
ln2.setAttribute("x2", width);
ln2.setAttribute("y2", heightMid);
ln2.setAttribute("stroke-width", ".5");
ln2.setAttribute("stroke", "green");
ln2.setAttribute("class", "YAxis");

svg.appendChild(ln2);

let tl2 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'title');
tl2.textContent = "YAxis";
svg.appendChild(tl2);

ln2.append(tl2);


let rect1 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
rect1.setAttribute("class", "testRect");
rect1.setAttribute("id", "testRect");
rect1.setAttribute("x", "150")
rect1.setAttribute("y", "150")
rect1.setAttribute("width", "20");
rect1.setAttribute("height", "20");
rect1.setAttribute("fill", "blue");

let tl3 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'title');
tl3.textContent = "test Rect (original location 150,150)";
svg.appendChild(tl3);

rect1.append(tl3);

svg.appendChild(rect1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    
    
    <script href="index.js"></script>

    
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

The above generates this.

`<rect class="testRect" id="testRect" x="150" y="150" width="20" height="20" fill="blue"><title>test Rect (original location 150,150)</title></rect>`

When I apply svg transform on the above element like

`rect1.setAttribute("transform", "translate (100,0)");` the new coordinate becomes `(250,0)`.

[image: S1]
Coded differently, if I had not applied transform at all, the markup for `<rect>` would have been

`<rect class="testRect" id="testRect" x="250" y="150" width="20" height="20" fill="blue"><title>test Rect (original location 150,150)</title></rect>`

which is the same as the following with `transform`

`<rect class="testRect" id="testRect" x="150" y="150" width="20" height="20" fill="blue" transform="translate (100,0)"><title>test Rect (original location 150,150)</title></rect>`

Similarly, if I apply the following transformation, `rect1.setAttribute("transform", "translate (100,0) scale(1,.5)");`

[image: S2]

I create a `<rect>` that would be

`<rect class="testRect" id="testRect" x="250" y="150" width="20" height="10" fill="blue" "><title>test Rect (original location 150,150)</title></rect>`

which would be same as the following with `transform`

`<rect class="testRect" id="testRect" x="150" y="150" width="20" height="20" fill="blue" transform="translate (100,0) scale(1,.5)"><title>test Rect (original location 150,150)</title></rect>`

Is there any way, Javascript can give me the new coordinate (x,y) and the dimension (height,width)of the svg element that has already taken into account the effect of transform, without requiring me to do any `transform`(translate,rotate,scale,skew) related calculation at all for any kind of svg element if I want to understand the effect of transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call [consolidate](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#InterfaceSVGTransformList) on the SVGTransformList (that way we combine all the matrices into one), then do matrix multiplication i.e. create a SVGPoint and call matrixTransform

You can pass whatever values you want into the matrix transform so you can adapt this to other shapes as you wish.

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
const rect = document.getElementById('testRect');

const transformPoint = (svg, x, y, matrix) => {
  let p = svg.createSVGPoint();
  p.x = x;
  p.y = y;
  return p.matrixTransform(matrix);
};

rect.transform.baseVal.consolidate();
const p = transformPoint(svg, rect.x.baseVal.value, rect.y.baseVal.value, rect.transform.baseVal[0].matrix);
console.log(p.x + ", " + p.y);
```

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 500" width="400">
  <rect class="testRect" id="testRect" x="150" y="150" width="20" height="20" fill="blue" transform="translate (100,0) scale(2)"><title>test Rect (original location 150,150)</title></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This is awesome.  I am guessing `transform="translate (100,0) scale(2)"` not only  affects `x` and `y`, it also impacts `height` and `width`. Is it possible to get the new height and width as well? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, I'll leave that as an exercise for you to do since I've shown you how.

Comment: I have tried like this `const transformPoint2 = (svg, width, height, matrix) => {let p = svg.createSVGPoint();p.x = width;p.y = height;return p.matrixTransform(matrix);};` `console.log(transformPoint2(svg, rect.width.baseVal.value, rect.height.baseVal.value, rect.transform.baseVal[0].matrix))`. Is this the correct approach to get new height and width? If yes, it is currently giving me `SVGPoint {x: 140, y: 40}` whereas I was expecting `SVGPoint {x: 40, y: 40}` where x=width and y = height.

Comment: width and height are relative, calculate the bottom corner then subtract the top corner to find the width and height

Comment: I am asking if I can avoid doing all the calculations by myself to get all the new attributes of the `svg` element after `transform`. What you showed, correctly gets new x and y. What I tried, requires additional calculations. There are elements in the svg document which has multiple transformations. If I need to get the new x,y and other dimensions, it requires me to understand the intricacies of each transform effect accurately, which I currently don't know. Hence, I was asking if javascript  API can correctly give all the details (e.g. x,y,height,width) I need. Thanks.

Comment: Nope it cannot.